# Minimising $\arg(z)$ given that $\lvert z -5 +7i \rvert = 5$?

Tags: calculus

I know this can be solved using geometry but given that it involves minimising a value, I was wondering if there is a way to solve this using calculus? Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: 
The equation represents a circle with centre $(5,-7)$ and radius $5$. We can use the parametric equation of the circle, i.e. let $x=5+5\cos \theta$ and $y= -7+5\sin \theta$. Therefore $$\tan(\arg(z))= \frac{y}{x} = \frac{-7+5\sin \theta}{5+5\cos \theta}$$ which needs to be minimised with respect to $\theta$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Sorry!, I'll fix it immediately :)

Answer (score 0):

Note that the equation  $\lvert z -5 +7i \rvert = 5$ represents a circle with the center $(5, -7)$ and radius $5$ in the complex plane. So, it touches the imaginary axis at $(0,-5)$ from right, hence a minimum $\arg(z)=-\frac\pi2$.

Answer (score 0):

$z$ makes a circle of radius 5 around the point $(5,-7)$ So, the extremum values of the argument will be minimum by taking the tangents to the circle from the origin. One of them 2ill give the the highest and other the lowest absolute values.

[image]

So, the angle intercepted by these tangent lines is $2tan^{-1}(\frac{5}{7})$. So, the minimum absolute value of the argument will be $\frac{π}{2}-2{tan^{-1}(\frac{5}{7})}$ .

And the maximum absolute value is $\frac{π}{2}$.